# CSS: Why are my three columns being split?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a react app using Next.js but I am having issues with the CSS.

I have the following defined home.module.css:

```
.grid_container {
  /* display: grid; */
  /* grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; */
  /* column-count: 3;
  align-items: flex-start; */
  /* align-content: space-evenly; */
  align-items: stretch;
  column-count: 3;
  /* column-gap: 500px; */
  border: solid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left_pane {
  justify-content: left;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
}

.center_pane {
  justify-content: left;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}

.right_pane {
  justify-content: left;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Then I have index.js:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.grid_container}>
      <div>
        <div className={styles.left_pane}>
          <h2>Left Pane</h2>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.center_pane}>
          <h2>Center Pane</h2>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.right_pane}>
          <h2>Right Pane</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Result:
[image: Why is it wrapping the column?]

Why is it wrapping the columns like that? I want 3 columns that occupy the whole frame.

```css
.grid_container {
  /* display: grid; */
  /* grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; */
  /* column-count: 3;
  align-items: flex-start; */
  /* align-content: space-evenly; */
  align-items: stretch;
  column-count: 3;
  /* column-gap: 500px; */
  border: solid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left_pane {
  justify-content: left;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
}

.center_pane {
  justify-content: left;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}

.right_pane {
  justify-content: left;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid_container">
    <div class="left_pane">
      <h2>Left Pane</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="center_pane">
      <h2>Center Pane</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="right_pane">
      <h2>Right Pane</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe convert your code into html and css so you can use the snippet function of SO. This is hard to engage with

Comment: Because you seem to have an inner container which is in the first column....what is the purpose of the inner container?

Comment: @Paulie_D If you are referring to the extra <div> I took that out and it is still the same. If not, I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS grid you specify column widths in the `grid-template-columns` property, and the row heights with the `grid-template-rows` property. You don't use floats or the `width` property. Also, since a div element is block already, it's full width by default. Finally, the elements immediately inside your container are what are considered the columns. You had an extra wrapping div in there.

I suggest a glance at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid.

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  border: solid;
}

.grid_container .pane {
  justify-content: left;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
  <div class="pane">
    <h2>Left Pane</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <h2>Center Pane</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <h2>Right Pane</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```